# Replace System.Diagnostics into .Net Core 2.0 (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.diagnostics

I got method in **console app .net 4.6**:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public static void CPUMonitorTest()
{
   var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
   ...
}
```

When try to do it into **class library .NET Core 2.0** I got problem:

- the namespace doesn't exisit

What can I do now?

Comment: You can try to install that dependency: https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need package System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter. Install it using package manager or console

```
Install-Package System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter -Version 4.5.0
```

[image]